# Json data parsing Codename one

Tags: java, json, codenameone

I am getting the Json response from my symfony web app.

```
[
{
"Id": 15,
"trackingcode": "LVREF45771",
"Datecreation": {
"date": "2015-01-01 00:00:00.000000",
"timezone_type": 3,
"timezone": "Europe\/Berlin"
},
"Status": "Delivered",
"Livreur": {
"image": "d81aa404f6afd393ebf6e00bf87d4107.jpeg",
"idlivreur": 1,
"nom": "Aramex",
"prenom": "Aramex",
"adresse": "Aramex Adresse",
"numtel": 96250615,
"active": null,
"commandes": []
}
},
{
"Id": 16,
"trackingcode": null,
"Datecreation": {
"date": "2015-01-01 00:00:00.000000",
"timezone_type": 3,
"timezone": "Europe\/Berlin"
},
"Status": "Not delivered",
"Livreur": {
"image": "62d44c60a0ded39190552a7677a59bb3.jpeg",
"idlivreur": 2,
"nom": "FedEx",
"prenom": "Livraison",
"adresse": "FedEx adresse",
"numtel": 96250615,
"active": null,
"commandes": []
}
}
]
```

I am currently working on a mobile app using CodeNameOne.  I've successfully parsed some data such as "Id" "trackingcode"

My problem is I didn't find a proper way to access "Livreur" fields ( image , idLivreur ... )

Here is my code for parsing

```
JSONParser j = new JSONParser();
            Map<String, Object> tasksListJson = j.parseJSON(new CharArrayReader(jsonText.toCharArray()));

            List<Map<String, Object>> list = (List<Map<String, Object>>) tasksListJson.get("root");

            for (Map<String, Object> obj : list) {
                Livraison livraison = new Livraison();
                float id = Float.parseFloat(obj.get("Id").toString());
                livraison.setIdLivraison((int) id);
                if (obj.get("trackingcode") == null) {
                    livraison.setTrackingCode("NO TRACKING CODE");

                } else {
                    livraison.setTrackingCode(obj.get("trackingcode").toString());
                }

                livraison.setStatus(obj.get("Status").toString());
```

Comment: which `JSONParser` library is that?

Comment: com.codename1.io.JSONParser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got 99% of the way:

```
for (Map<String, Object> obj : list) {
    // ...
    Map<String, Object> livreur = obj.get("Livreur");
    String livreurImage = (String)liverur.get("image");
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access like this.

```
if (obj.get("Livreur") == null) {
      Map<String, Object> data = (Map<String, Object>) obj.get("Livreur");
     // now access inner fields like this.

     data.get("image");
}
```

Or you can make use of beautiful `Jackson` library. You can simply create a structure like this. (don't forget to add getter/setter)

```
class Livreur {
    private String image;
    // others 
}

class WhateverNameYouWant {
    private int id;
    private String trackingcode;
    // and others

    private Livreur livreur;

    //you can add similarly for date creation and others.
}
```

Now change your reader part.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<WhateverNameYouWant> list = mapper.readValue(payload, new TypeReference<List<WhateverNameYouWant>>(){});
```

As your fields seem to be mixed case, register case insensitive

```
mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
```

And you can use the following to ignore unwanted fields.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class WhateverNameYouWant { }

// similarly on other classes
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried that before the WhatEverNameYouWant class in my case is called Livraison and I get a casting exception when trying to store the elements in a list as you mentioned 

Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException - java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to Entites.Livraison
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to Entites.Livraison

Comment: Should I use jackson in this case?

Comment: I've managed to fix this problem by storing the "Livreur" part in a LinkedHashMap 
     LinkedHashMap<String, Object> lhm = (LinkedHashMap<String, Object>) obj.get("Livreur");
and to access the elements I used the classic get method                 livreur.setAdresse((String)lhm.get("adresse"));

I know this might not look like a good solution but it kinda did the job.

I've checked your updated answer and it seems like a more practical way and a better solution , I'll definitely try it , Thank you!